# Convert value in text box to href or hyperlink on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some of your expert advice! I've been struggling with this problem the whole day.

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fag9n52y/109/

I've commented what the scripts do as well as commented what my main issue is in the "HTML" section of the fiddle.

**How the form works:**

1. User clicks on "Coordinate1" text input.
2. Google Maps modal popup initiates.
3. User then chooses a location on the map.
4. Once an eventclick is triggered on the map, the coordinates of the location are automatically inserted into the textbox.
5. User clicks "Continue" button.
6. End.

**What I need to happen:**

1. User clicks on "Coordinate1" text input.
2. Google Maps modal popup initiates.
3. User then chooses a location on the map.
4. Once an eventclick is triggered on the map, the coordinates of the location are automatically inserted into the textbox.
5. User clicks "Continue" button.
6. The coordinates are converted into this hyperlink/href: "https://www.google.com/maps/places/ + {VALUE OF COORDINATE1}".
7. End.

**What I've tried: I've tried adding this piece of code(This isn't in the fiddle):**

```
function convertToLink() {
  var coor = document.getElementById('Coordinate1');
  var link2 = "https://www.google.com/maps/places";
  var ContinueButton = document.getElementById('Continue1');

  ContinueButton.onclick = function(){
    coor.value = link2 + coor;         
  };                       
};
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` to create a [mcve]

Comment: `coor.value = link2 + coor;` this is incorrect. coor is a html element, link2 is a string. So literarily this reads: Set the value of coor to the string plus the element itsself. You probably want `coor.value = link2 + coor.value`

Comment: Alright thanks a lot dude will give it a try!

Comment: What's about this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fag9n52y/113/) ?

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola That is working almost precisely in the way I wanted. The only change is that it must be "place/" instead of "places/". (Or to me the "places" doesn't work). Now I need to do this exact scenario, but with the "continue" button. I think I'll be able to work from your piece of coding! Thanks a lot man!!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` returns a dom node but you need the value of that node

Change

```
var coor = document.getElementById('Coordinate1');
```

To

```
var coor = document.getElementById('Coordinate1').value;
```

Comment: `$("#Coordinate1").val()`